# Does the number of App instances and Zookeeper servers should be the same?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

Does the number of App instances and Zookeeper servers should be the same? I understand the requirement of 2F+1 to tolerate F failures but this is to tolerate failures of Zookeeper instances itself. But how about the number of App instances ? For example say I have 3 zookeeper servers and I have 2 instances of my APP running that are managed by zookeeper and at any given time only one instance of my App will be running in master mode and the other in standby mode. Now, I want to be able to tolerate one instance failure of my APP itself (not the zookeeper instance) such that the other instance of my APP which was running in a standby mode should be elected as a new leader. Would that work? or I must have 3 instances of my App and 3 Zookeeper servers?

What is the right configuration for number of App instances and Zookeeper servers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the perspective of ZooKeeper, there is no requirement on running any particular number of application instances.  The application instances are ZooKeeper clients.  They are not members of the ZooKeeper ensemble (the server side), so they are not subject to the 2F+1 fault tolerance requirement.

The number of application instances may impact overall availability of your application though, depending on its design.  (As you said in your example, you can run 2 instances and it would tolerate 1 failure.)

Note that your application's leader election is different from the ZooKeeper ensemble's internal leader election.  Within the ZooKeeper ensemble, a quorum of servers (2F+1) is required to elect a leader, and then that ZooKeeper ensemble leader processes transaction proposals from clients.  At the application layer, your code acts as a ZooKeeper client and performs its own leader election using something like the [Leader Election](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.9/recipes.html#sc_leaderElection) recipe or the [Apache Curator Leader Election](http://curator.apache.org/curator-recipes/leader-election.html) API.  The ZooKeeper ensemble nodes are not voting on which one of your application nodes becomes leader.  Instead, your application nodes are voting on which one of them becomes leader, and they vote by coordination with the ZooKeeper ensemble, which already has its own leader.

Comment: How can It tolerate one app instance failure? since only one of my application instance needs to be run as a master and others needs to be run as standby. The moment one of my application instance fails the leader election should run so in my case I will be left with only one app instance hence the leader election wont work right?

Comment: No, the leader election for your app can still succeed.  In fact, the architecture you described is identical to how the HDFS NameNode achieves high availability: a master and a standby coordinate leadership through ZooKeeper.  You might be thinking of the ZooKeeper ensemble's own internal leader election, which does require a quorum (2F+1 instances), but this is different from your app's leader election.

Comment: @user1870400 read more about implementation of application level leader election in [ZK recipes docs](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.5.2-alpha/recipes.html#sc_leaderElection).

Comment: @Chris Nauroth so say I have 3 ZK servers in total which means I can tolerate one failure and say I have 2 instances of my app running. if one ZK instance fails I will be left with 2 ZK servers and now say ZK server1 votes for App instance 1 and ZK server2 votes for App instance 2. How will Zookeeper elects a leader for my app in this case?

Comment: @user1870400 The ZooKeeper ensemble nodes do not actually vote for app instance 1 or instance 2.  Instead, your app instances are voting for which app instance becomes leader, and their leader election is implemented by coordinating transactions with the ZooKeeper ensemble.  The ZooKeeper ensemble already elected its own leader internally, but this is different from your application deciding which instance becomes leader.  I have edited the answer to clarify this.  I also echo the recommendation to read the leader election recipe and also consider Apache Curator.